# Base class pure virtual functions with templated derived class

Tags: c++, templates, polymorphism

I am attempting to use polymorphism with a templated derived class. Consider the following code:

```
// base class
class A {
  public:
  virtual void f() = 0;
};

// templated derived class
template< typename T >
class B : public A {};

template <> //define a specialization of B
class B< int > {};

// trying to define a specialization of f
template <>
void B< int >::f() {}
```

My base class has the pure virtual function `f`. I am storing a vector of base class pointers `A*` and would like to call `f` on all of them, with appropriate polymorphism on the templated derived class. However, I am unable to define specializations of f, as I receive the following error:

```
test.cpp:17:18: error: no member function ‘f’ declared in ‘B<int>’ void B< int >::f() {}
```

Obviously the error here is that `f` is not actually a member function of the templated class. Is there any way to define specializations of f (or something nearly equivalent), or is this simply not possible? If it is not possible, can you suggest another approach?

[Apologies if this is a duplicate--I searched and found many variations of questions on templating, inheritance, and polymorphism, but none that exactly matched mine.]

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
template <> //define a specialization of B
class B< int > {};
```

Your specialization does not define the overriden virtual function. Change this specialization to:

```
template <> //define a specialization of B
class B< int > : public A
{
  public:
      void f() override;
}
```

A specialization is like defining a new class. You have to define everything that's in it. If the specialization should have a particular method: define it.

EDIT: also corrected the typo inherited from the original question.

Comment: Shouldn't the specialization also inherit from `A`?

Comment: Thank you, this resolves the problem (though there were a couple of additional bugs in my code). @Rakete1111 is correct that the specialization needs to inherit from A in order for the polymorphism to work, I missed that.